# Nested inner joins in linq to sql?

Tags: linq-to-sql

After quick overview I didn't find how to deal with linq to sql if I have several nested inner joins.

That's what I'd like to have in linq

```
SELECT Booking.BookingId, Booking.EventId, Booking.StartDate, Event.Name, Person.FirstName
FROM Booking
    INNER JOIN Event 
        INNER JOIN Asset
        ON Asset.AssetId = Event.AssetId
        INNER JOIN Person
        ON Person.PersonId = Event.ContactPersonId
    ON Event.EventId = Booking.EventId AND Event.State = 4
```

Does anyone know how to translate it to LINQ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q1= from a in booking,b in event,c in asset, d in person where a.eventid=b.eventid and b.state=4 and c.assetid = b.assetid and b.contactpersonid=d.personid select a,b,c,d
```

you can replace a,b,c,d at then with the column names you want

another way is to use the join keyword:

```
var w1= from a in booking join b in event on a.eventid equals b.eventid join c in asset on ...
```

Comment: Thank you, also figured out how to do it and used approach like you suggested in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from b in context.Bookings
    from e in context.Events
    join a in context.Assets on e.AssetId equals a.AssetId
    join p in context.People on e.ContactPersonId equals p.PersonId
    where e.State == (byte)States.Approved && e.EventId == b.EventId
    select new { EventName = e.Name, BookingDate = b.StartDate };
```